# Cyclic number shift to the right byte by byte

Tags: c++, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, function-definition

The program takes two numbers as input: num - a number for which a right cyclic shift must be performed byte by byte, and bytes - the number of bytes by which it must be shifted to the right.

The program works correctly only when shifting bytes for the value of 1. If asked to shift bytes for any other number, the output is not correct. What's wrong here?

```
unsigned long long shiftr(unsigned long long num, unsigned char bytes) {
    unsigned long long mask;
        switch (bytes)
        {
        case 1: 
            mask = 0xFF;
            break;
        case 2:
            mask = 0xFFFF;
            break;
        case 3:
            mask = 0xFFFFFF;
            break;
        case 4:
            mask = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            break;
        case 5:
            mask = 0xFFFFFFFFFF;
            break;
        case 6:
            mask = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF;
            break;
        case 7:
            mask = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
            break;
        case 8:
            mask = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
            break;
        default:;
        }
        
        num = mask & ( ((num & 0x1) << (bytes * 8 - 1)) | (num >> 1) );
        return num;
}
```

With the value `num` = 1, the shift is performed correctly in all cases. But if you enter another number, the program will not work correctly. Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression used in this assignment statement

```
num = mask & ( ((num & 0x1) << (bytes * 8 - 1)) | (num >> 1) );
```

is wrong. For example this sub-expression `(num & 0x1)` extract only the first bit of the number that is shifted to the left while this sub-expression `(num >> 1)` moves the number to the right only by one bit.

Also you need to check the value of the parameter `bytes` that is not greater than 8.

Pay attention to that the parameter `bytes` specifies the number of bytes to shift not bits.

Using your approach the function can look the following way as shown in the demonstration program below.

```
#include <iostream>

unsigned long long shiftr( unsigned long long num, unsigned char bytes )
{
    const size_t N = sizeof( num );

    bytes %= N;

    if ( bytes != 0 )
    {
        unsigned long long  mask;

        switch (bytes)
        {
        case 1:
            mask = 0xFF;
            break;
        case 2:
            mask = 0xFFFF;
            break;
        case 3:
            mask = 0xFFFFFF;
            break;
        case 4:
            mask = 0xFFFFFFFF;
            break;
        case 5:
            mask = 0xFFFFFFFFFF;
            break;
        case 6:
            mask = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFF;
            break;
        case 7:
            mask = 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFF;
            break;
        }

        num = ( mask & num ) << 8 * ( N - bytes ) | num >> 8 * bytes;
    }

    return num;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned long long num = 0x123456789ABCDEF0;

    for (unsigned char bytes = 0; bytes < 8; ++bytes)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << num << ": " << shiftr( num, bytes ) << '\n';
    }
}
```

The program output is

```
123456789abcdef0: 123456789abcdef0
123456789abcdef0: f0123456789abcde
123456789abcdef0: def0123456789abc
123456789abcdef0: bcdef0123456789a
123456789abcdef0: 9abcdef012345678
123456789abcdef0: 789abcdef0123456
123456789abcdef0: 56789abcdef01234
123456789abcdef0: 3456789abcdef012
```

Comment: Do you mean to say that the number 1 after a cyclic shift to the right became equal to 16384? It's not right. It should be equal to 256. This is your program's response.

Comment: @nnn I have not understood what you wrote. If you have the number 1 like 0x0000000000000001 then after shifting to the right you will have 0x0100000000000000.

Comment: если 1 сдвинуть на 1 байт вправо, то получится `0x0000 0001 0000 0000`. В одном байте 8 бит. А вы в программе сдвинули, получается, на 12 битов, раз получилось `0x0100 0000 0000 0000`. Почему моё мнение неверно? В таком случае у вас 1 байт равен 12 битам

Comment: @nnn This record 0x01 means a hexadecimal record of the number 1 that occupies one byte. As your function parameter has the type unsigned long long then a number of that type occupies 8 bytes and 1 in hex will be represented  like 0x0000000000000001. To move the last byte 0x01 to the right you will get 0x0100000000000000

Answer (score 0):

**By making a simple drawing**, we can see what to shift and by how many bits. The '8 * num' bits at right will become at the left of the result.

```
Before:
    AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABBBBBBB   symbolize the initial number
                    <----->   8 * num, we highlight the bits that go around
After:
1)  .......AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA shifted ?? bits to right
2)  BBBBBBB.................. shifted ?? bits to left
3) regroup to make a number
```

Notice that, here we do not need a mask. In case 1, we can shift the whole number (new bits at left will be filled of 0 and old bits at right shifted outside). Same for case 2.
In case 1, the number of bits for right shift is obvious.
In case 2, the number of bits is almost simple.

Answer (score 0):

> Why is that?

Because the formula is clearly wrong and it doesn't even work for 1.

E.g. for `num = 1; bytes = 1` you've got

```
mask = 0xFF;
(num & 0x1) = 0x1
(bytes * 8 - 1) = 7
((num & 0x1) << (bytes * 8 - 1)) = 0x80
(num >> 1) = 0
( ((num & 0x1) << (bytes * 8 - 1)) | (num >> 1) ) = 0x80
mask & ( ((num & 0x1) << (bytes * 8 - 1)) | (num >> 1) ) = 0x80
```

This is neither a right shift nor a shift by 8 bits.

In fact any shift by an number bytes other than 8 cannot result in the correct output for all possible values of `num`, since you do a bitwise AND with `mask` just before returning and any mask that's not all 1 bits will drop some bits for some other operand for the bitwise AND.

Note that when shifting any bits moved into places the target type has no bits for are simply dropped which makes the it possible to simply combine the rightshifted part leftshifted by `64 - 8 * bytesToShiftRight`.

I recomment using fixed-size integral types when relying on a specific number of bits btw:

```
constexpr uint64_t shiftrBits(uint64_t num, unsigned bits)
{
    bits %= 64;
    return (bits == 0) ? num : (num >> bits) | (num << (64u - bits));
}

constexpr uint64_t shiftr(uint64_t num, unsigned char bytes) {
    return shiftrBits(num, 8 * bytes);
}

static_assert(shiftr(0x0000000000000001, 0) == 0x0000000000000001);
static_assert(shiftr(0x0000000000000001, 1) == 0x0100000000000000);
static_assert(shiftr(0x0000000000000001, 2) == 0x0001000000000000);
static_assert(shiftr(0x0000000000000001, 3) == 0x0000010000000000);
static_assert(shiftr(0x0000000000000001, 4) == 0x0000000100000000);
static_assert(shiftr(0x0000000000000001, 5) == 0x0000000001000000);
static_assert(shiftr(0x0000000000000001, 6) == 0x0000000000010000);
static_assert(shiftr(0x0000000000000001, 7) == 0x0000000000000100);
static_assert(shiftr(0x0000000000000001, 8) == 0x0000000000000001);
static_assert(shiftr(0x1000100001000001, 4) == 0x0100000110001000);
```